# Ruby Object mutations within sidekiq workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thread-safety, sidekiq

I have a wrapper that sends user updates to an external service, on a regular basis, running inside a Sidekiq worker. Each User has its own Sidekiq Job. Sidekiq is setup to use 20 threads. It's a Rails 5.0.1 app, MRI Ruby 2.3.0. Webserver is Passenger 5 Community.

If I over simplify, the code looks like this:

```
class ProviderUserUpdateJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(user_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    Provider::User.new(user).push_update
  end
end


class Provider::User 

  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def push_update
    SomeApiWrapper.call(
      user_id: @user.id,
      status: @user.status
    )
  end

  ....
end
```

Now, the BIG problem that I only have on production and I finally catched up by looking at the logs can be summarized like this :

```
class Provider::User 

  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def push_update
    SomeApiWrapper.call(
      user_id: @user.id,    # Some user
      status: @user.status  # NOT THE SAME USER !!! (and I have no idea where he is coming from)
    )
  end

  ....
end
```

2 Questions:

1. How it this even possible? Does it comes from Provider::User being by essence a globally accessible object, so, from threads to threads, everything gets mixed up in a mutating soup?!
2. If I only use "functional" style, without any instance, passing parameters and outputs from static methods to static methods, can it solve my problem or am I completely wrong? How can I fix this?

Ultimately, is there any way to really battle test this kind of code so I can be sure not to mix users data?

Comment: _"If I over simplify, the code looks like this"_ – and does the bug still occur with that simplified code?

Comment: Haha, ok. My bad. But although it is simplified, the exact place and behavior of the problem stay the same as in the original code: "@user" is pointing to something else, from one line to another, randomly, on production. There is absolutely nothing between the 2 consecutive calls to "@user" variable, and this, is not simplified here.

Comment: Could the calls to `id` or `status` have side effects that mutate the receiver? If not, is `SomeApiWrapper.call` thread safe?

Comment: Without knowing what else `Provider::User` does, I'd make it stateless, so you can call `Provider::User.push_update(user)` on it.

Comment: @stefan : actually, `SomeApiWrapper.call` only wraps the content of this hash into an XML file then POST it to an external API. It does not do anything special on "@user".

Comment: @Wukerplank : that's exactly what I was thinking about. Do you think doing so will reduce (avoid?) mutations risks? I can't figure out when something is "thread safe" or not, especially with Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... turns out it's a dummy data issue. I just lost 2 hours trying to figure it out with complicated explanations but the answer was, simply, in my DB. Well done :-/